# Convert from T-SQL to Access query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Is there a convenient way to convert this T-SQL query to MS Access? The `ROUND` and `COALESCE` doesn't seem to work in Access.
I'm trying to get the custom `AVG` field to run in Access but always gets the *syntax error (missing operator)*.

```
SELECT TOP 50 [EmployeeID]
    ,[Last Name]
    ,[First Name]
    ,[HrsThisWk]

    --AVG HRs
    ,ROUND(
     coalesce((
        coalesce([1WksAgo],0) +
        coalesce([2WksAgo],0) +
        coalesce([3WksAgo],0) +
        coalesce([4WksAgo],0) +
        coalesce([5WksAgo],0)
      )/
      nullif(
        case when coalesce([1WksAgo],0)=0 then 0 else 1 end +
        case when coalesce([2WksAgo],0)=0 then 0 else 1 end +
        case when coalesce([3WksAgo],0)=0 then 0 else 1 end +
        case when coalesce([4WksAgo],0)=0 then 0 else 1 end +
        case when coalesce([5WksAgo],0)=0 then 0 else 1 end,
      0),0), 2)
      AS '--- AVG HRs ---'

    ,[1WksAgo]
    ,[2WksAgo]
    ,[3WksAgo]
    ,[4WksAgo]
    ,[5WksAgo]

FROM [CMHR].[dbo].[tbl52weekHours_20150527]
GROUP BY
    [EmployeeID]
    ,[Last Name]
    ,[First Name]
    ,[HrsThisWk]
    ,[1WksAgo]
    ,[2WksAgo]
    ,[3WksAgo]
    ,[4WksAgo]
    ,[5WksAgo]
```

[image]

Comment: can you post the query you are trying to execute in access

Comment: I have Wk1 to Wk52 columns but Access has limitation of total characters allowed in a query.....

Comment: There is no way to "convert" this to Access SQL. A total redesign from scratch is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`NZ`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/nz.php) instead of `COALESCE` and `NULLIF`, and [`IIF`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php) instead of `CASE WHEN` and `"..."` instead of `[...]` like this:

```
SELECT TOP(50) "EmployeeID"
    ,"Last Name"
    ,"First Name"
    ,"HrsThisWk"
    ,ROUND(
      NZ((
        NZ("1WksAgo",0) +
        NZ("2WksAgo",0) +
        NZ("3WksAgo",0) +
        NZ("4WksAgo",0) +
        NZ("5WksAgo",0)
      )/
      NZ(
        IIF(NZ("1WksAgo",0)=0, 0, 1) +
        IIF(NZ("2WksAgo",0)=0, 0, 1) +
        IIF(NZ("3WksAgo",0)=0, 0, 1) +
        IIF(NZ("4WksAgo",0)=0, 0, 1) +
        IIF(NZ("5WksAgo",0)=0, 0, 1),
      0),0), 2)
      AS "AVG HRs"

  ,"1WksAgo"
  ,"2WksAgo"
  ,"3WksAgo"
  ,"4WksAgo"
  ,"5WksAgo"

  FROM "tbl52weekHours_20150527"
  GROUP BY
   "EmployeeID"
  ,"Last Name"
  ,"First Name"
  ,"HrsThisWk"
  ,"1WksAgo"
  ,"2WksAgo"
  ,"3WksAgo"
  ,"4WksAgo"
  ,"5WksAgo"
```

You can create your query without `TOP(50)` and then set the [Top Values property](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/top_results.php) to `50`.